# How to Write Pattern (regex_pattern) to select 5 days of data from S3 Prefix in snowflake copy pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Requirement:**

partitioned parquet file is stored in S3 in below prefix and use case is to load  5 days of data ( 2012-01-01 **-** 2012-01-05) into snowflake variant table. So thought to use Pattern to accomplish this, any suggestion how to write regexp?

````
copy into amazon-reviews-pds
from @amazon-reviews-pds
pattern = <>

s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**01** 00.snapppy.parquet
s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**01** 01.snapppy.parquet

s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**02** 00.snapppy.parquet
s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**03** 00.snapppy.parquet
s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**04** 00.snapppy.parquet
s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**05** 00.snapppy.parquet
s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**06** 00.snapppy.parquet
      .
      .
      .
s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**10** 00.snapppy.parquet
      .
      .
s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/date_dt=2012-01-**31** 00.snapppy.parquet```
````

Comment: while it seems like a patter works for 2012-01-01 to 06 what happens when you have `2012-12-30,-31,2013-01-01,02,03` which can be written still with patterns, but that pattern is day range specific, at which point you might be better off just using 5 group set

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://regexr.com/ to test your regular expressions.

This pattern should work:

```
copy into amazonreviewspds
from @amazonreviewspds 
pattern='.*parquet/date_dt=2012-01-0[15].*';
```

You can test it using LS command:

```
ls @amazonreviewspds pattern='.*parquet/date_dt=2012-01-0[15].*';
```

If you want to load first five days for each month, you can modify the expression like:

```
ls @amazonreviewspds pattern='.*parquet/date_dt=2012-\\d{2}-0[15].*';
```